# How to pass a function as argument to another function and use the value returned by that function in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to negate the value returned by one function.

Consider the code to be

```
def greater(a,b):
    return a>b

check = negate(greater)

assert check(8,9)
```

OR

```
def equal(a,b):
    return a==b

check = negate(equal)

assert check("python","java")
```

How should I define the ***NEGATE*** function???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
def negate(func):
  def result(*args):
    return not func(*args)
  return result
```

This is a function which creates a function which returns the result of invoking the original function and `not`ing it's return value, and then returning that function.

Comment: @RiteshBhat: Sure. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a function-style [decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator):

```
def negate(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return not val
    return inner
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> greater(10, 20)
False
>>> negate(greater)(10, 20)
True
```

To preserve things like `docstring` and other attributes of the function being passed to `negate` you can use [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

```
from functools import wraps

def negate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return not val
    return inner
```

Comment: Are you copying Martijns edits?  One of you guys should just delete your answer ..

Comment: @wim His original answer was incorrect, I am not copying anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `not` operator in a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def negate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        return not func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

The above decorator returns a wrapper function that applies `not` to the return value of the wrapped function. The [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in the above example is optional but makes sure the wrapper gains the docstring and other introspectable attributes from the original function, making it behave more closely like the wrapped function.

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def negate(func):
...     @wraps(func)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kw):
...         return not func(*args, **kw)
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> def greater(a,b):
...     return a>b
... 
>>> check = negate(greater)
>>> check(8, 9)
True
```

Comment: I did try that but it shows    TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: Try again, I missed a nuance of your question.

Comment: It might not be appropriate to use wraps in this use case, copying the docstring and all ...